# How to get a menu checkbutton to call a function in Python + Tkinter?

Tags: python, function, checkbox, tkinter

so, I'm now in a personal project (just to try myself) with python + tkinter. It is a encrypter, which means that it gets a piece of text and encrypts it using some famous cyphers (like the numerical cypher, the caesar's cypher, and others).
Now, I wanted to give the user the option to save the text he encrypted, and also the encrypted text generated by the program. For that, I created two checkbutton on the program's menu: one for "save text" and the other for "save encrypted text". My question is, I tried to attach a function as it's command option, so, I guess it should run that function when the option is clicked. But it isn't happening.
I'll just explain what the funcitions shouls do before passing the code.
They should prompt a question, asking the user if he/she really wants to create a text file with the text and the encrypted text (This isn't a database, it's just something for the user to be able to read later the text's he/she encrypted and the encrypted version, if he/she wants to).
So, to the code:

```
encryptermenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
encryptermenu.add_checkbutton(label="Save Text", variable=v, command=saveText)
encryptermenu.add_checkbutton(label="Save Encrypted Text", variable=w, command=saveEncryptedText)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Encrypter", menu=encryptermenu)
```

The checkbutton options, and now the functions:

```
def saveText():
    sdtst = messagebox.askyesno(title="Save Text", message="A .txt file will be created at the same directory as this program to save the text you decided to encrypt. Is it ok?")

def saveEncryptedText():
    sdtset = messagebox.askyesno(title="Save Encrypted Text", message="A .txt file will be created at the same directory as this program to save the encrypted text generated by this program. Is it ok?")
```

Should the checkbutton really run the function on-click or am I just making confusion?
Anyway, hope someone will help me.

Comment: Is it all code? Are there any error messages? Code seems correct for me. Except one thing: why do you use `add_checkbutton` instead of `add_command`?

Comment: No error messages, the only problem is that nothing happens. The checkbutton option is to create an menu option that is toggable, so it shows a tick when it is active, and doesn't when is inactive. I decided to use that because I would like to leave a tick whenever the text or the encrypted text were being saved, so that the user would know.

Answer (score 2):

Checkbutton Menu can definitely call a function. That is what the checkbutton option is there for :)

I generally use 2 functions to handle a call from the checkbutton menu.

first create that menu and assign it to a boolean var

```
yesno = BooleanVar(root)
mymenu.add_checkbutton(label="Do this ?", variable=yesno, command=mytoggle)
```

then you need 2 functions:
1) one callback to toggle 
2) one to handle yes

```
def mytoggle(event=None):
    val = yesno.get()
    if val:
        dosomething()
    else:
        somethingelse()
```

Comment: Still, when I click the check button option nothing happens. It was supposed to prompt a message box. I've created a function for calling the messagebox and a function for when the option is clicked and, yet, nothing happens when I click it. Also, it shows no error message or anything, it just doesn't happen.

Comment: @AugustoQ : you can always check where in your code you are getting stuck by printing out at each control line. For example within def mytoggle, after val = yesno.get(), you can print the value of val 'print val' to see what value the check button is passing to the variable 'val'

Answer (score 1):

To answer your specific question, yes, the function will be called when you click on the checkbutton.

You should be calling `add_command` rather than `add_checkbutton` on the menu. Using a checkbutton to call a function from a menu is highly unusual and will likely confuse your users.

Comment: The thing is, what I was going for was those buttons that get a tick when active, so the user could know when it was active and when it is not. But as I understand from you answer, i believe the checkbutton on the menu can't call a function, is that right? Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: Well, I decided not to prompt the user anymore, so my checkbuttons don't need to call a function.

Comment: @AugustoQ: no, you misunderstood. I clearly said the function _should_ be called even if you use a checkbutton.